# cakephp convert custom query to cakephp query

Tags: mysql, performance, cakephp, optimization

I have the following code in my projects controller's index action
I achieved it via custom queries
1- it is good to use custom queries?
2- how can I write the following queries using cakephp functions joins contains etc
3- which method will be good?

my tables are as below

```
portfolio_projects [id,name,....,user_id,job_id,manymore_id]   

portfolio_images   [id,project_id,image,orders,status,.....]

portfolio_tags     [id,tag,....]   

portfolio_project_tags[id,project_id,tag_id]
```

and query is as below. I did this to fetch only needed data that is projects with its images and tags but not project's (user,job and others)
there are other tables linked to tags, images tables too but I do not need that data here.

```
$this->Project->recursive = -1;
    $projects = $this->Project->find('all',array(
        'conditions' => array(
            'Project.user_id' => $this->Auth->user('id')
        )
    ));
    foreach($projects as $key=>$project)
    {
        //fetching project related tags starts here
        $q="select * from portfolio_project_tags where 0";
        $q="select tag.id as id,tag.tag from portfolio_project_tags as p left outer join portfolio_tags as tag on p.tag_id=tag.id where p.project_id=".$project['Project']['id'];
        $tags = $this->Project->query($q);
        $projects[$key]['Project']['tags']=$tags;
        //fetching project related tags ends here

        //fetching project related images starts here
        $q2="select * from portfolio_images where 0";
        $q2="select img.id as id,img.title as title, img.image as image from portfolio_images as img where img.project_id=".$project['Project']['id']." and img.status='Publish' order by orders";
        $snaps = $this->Project->query($q2);
        $projects[$key]['Project']['snaps']=$snaps;
        //fetching project related images ends here
    }
    $this->set('projects',$projects);
```

Comment: Why do you have 2 queries each time?

Comment: As for your first question, no, it is not good to use custom queries where you manually write out the query, instead of using the tools provided by the CakePHP framework.  The framework is there in part to help keep your queries secure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have 3 possibilities (at least) to retrieve data from a join table in CakePHP, that you should consider in the following order:

1. Containable Behaviour
2. CakePHP join query
3. Custom query

In your example, only the `q1` request need a join because the `q2` can be express as:

```
$this->PorfolioImage->find('all', array(
    'fields' => array('PortfolioImage.id, PortfolioImage.title, PortfolioImage.image'),
    'conditions' => array(
        'PortfolioImage.project_id' => $project['Project']['id']
    )
));
```

#### The containable behaviour

In your `Project` model, you could add information to the related models, such as:

```
class Model extends AppModel {
    public $actAs = array('Containable');
    public $hasMany = array('PortfolioImage'); 
    public $belongsTo = array('PortfolioTag') ;
}
```

Then, when you retrieve a `Project`, you have access to the related `PortfolioImage` and `Tag`, for example:

```
debug($this->Project->read(null, 1)) ;
```

Would output:

```
Array(
    'Project' => array(
        'id' => 1,
        /* other fields */
    ),
    'PortfolioTag' => array(
        'id' => /* */,
        'tag' => /* */
    ),
    'PortfolioImage' => array(
        0 => array(
            'id' => /* */,
            /* other fields */
        ),
        1 => array(/* */)
    )
)
```

You just need to be carefull on the naming of foreign key, the [CakePHP documentation about relationship](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/associations-linking-models-together.html) is really easy to read.

#### CakePHP join query

You can do a `join` query in CakePHP `find` method:

```
$this->Project->find('first', array(
    'fields' => array('Tag.id', 'Tag.title'),
    'joins' => array(
        'table' => 'portfolio_tags,
        'alias' => 'PortfolioTag',
        'type' => 'LEFT OUTER',
        'conditions' => array('PortfolioTag.id = Project.tag_id')
    )
)) ;
```

I'm really not used to CakePHP `join` queries (the `Containable` behaviour is often sufficient), but you'll find lot of information in the CakePHP documentation.

#### Custom queries

You should really not use custom queries except if you really know what you're doing because you have to take query of almost anything (sql injection at first place). At least, when doing custom queries, use **Prepared Statements** (see information at the end of [this link](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/retrieving-your-data.html)).